# cd: /path/to/my/repo: No such file or directory

Tags: bitbucket

I am trying to push my hello_app to my bitbucket repository.
I have an existing project and have trouble following these steps:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:Bob123/hello_app.git
git push -u origin --all 
git push -u origin --tags
```

When I `cd /path/to/my/repo` in my shell in cloud9, I get this error:

```
cd: /path/to/my/repo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like /path/to/my/repo folder doesn't exist. Are you sure you are typing correctly the path? If it doesn't exist, create the folder first, and then go ahead with the next step.

Comment: Are you literally typing "/path/to/my/repo"?

Comment: @DamiánMontenegro Where are you supposed to create the file, in the hello_app ? and if yes, should it be in any of the directories within hello_app or a new one

Comment: @NickVeys yea thats what I am typing

Comment: You need to replace /path/to... with the path to your repository.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the people with the problem resolved it, but here is how I fixed this problem.

Using this tutorial: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Import+code+from+an+existing+project

In your project's root directory, run:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

Then follow the steps from the initial page of the repo:

```
git remote add origin https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Hope I've helped someone!