# Can't push project files to bitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitbucket, cloud9-ide

I'm following along with Michael Hartl's rails tutorial. Here's an image of where I'm at:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Yve.png

My problem is the same as [cd: /path/to/my/repo: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796075/cd-path-to-my-repo-no-such-file-or-directory)

What is the path to my repository/How do I discover this on my own? I've tried just about everything. CD to get to the root of my project then using these commands, CD to go one folder lower, CD to go to project_name/.git before using the commands, etc. At this point, the output is always the same.

## 1: Using git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:[MyNameHere]/hello_app.git # Yields:

fatal: remote origin already exists.

## 2: git push -u origin --all # Yields:

No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

## 3: git push -u origin --tags # Yields the exact same results as the command above.

According to the tutorial, when I try to view my project on bitbucket I should be seeing all the files and folders. But no matter how many times I refresh, bitbucket swears that that project is completely empty, so I must be doing something wrong. What can I do to fix this? I'm thinking it has something to do with specifying the correct path to my repository, which I don't know how to do and the tutorial I'm reading has no mention of that step whatsoever, but bitbucket does. (The tutorial is outdated in several places so far, this being one of them.) Here's a picture of this discrepancy between bitbucket and the tutorial:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohjIW.png

Again, the tutorial makes no mention of the initial "cd" command and doesn't tell you how to specify the path from your cloud9 IDE to a repository on an entirely different website, bitbucket.

Comment: git commands are supposed to be used from the root folder of your project. Are you currently on the master branch? Try `git branch`, what does it say?

Comment: In 2 out of 3 of the directories I just tested, using "git branch" yields no (visible) results. Here's an image containing the 3 directories I just tried that command in: http://i.imgur.com/WHanzmm.png

Comment: Have you initialized your repo inside /workspace/hello_app with `git init`? .Git should be a hidden folder so ignore it now.

Comment: I did yesterday, and I have again just now today, after closing the project and shutting down my computer. (Yesterday, these "(master)" and "(GIT_DIR!)" tags didn't exist on my end; another side effect of picking up where I left off yesterday.) Sorry if this is a stupid question, but do I need to use git init inside workspace/hello_app every time I access my project and intend to do anything with it involving git? Also, after using git init just now, I tried following all the same steps in the original post and encountered all of the same messages. Refreshing bitbucket = repo is still empty.

Comment: Do you have already files inside hello_app folder? If not, create one just for test, then run `git add .` and then again `git push -u origin master`, obviously from /workspace/hello_app folder.

Comment: Yeah, there are already some files inside hello_app. Here are the results: http://i.imgur.com/JEnJFIF.png Refreshing https://bitbucket.org/[MyName]/hello_app has the same result: it's still empty and is still on the default page. "Repository setup
Your repository is empty — let's put some bits in your bucket." etc.

Comment: Maybe you should create another project on your computer, copy the files you need from the old one and then run in this order from /workspace/mynewproject folder: `git init` `git add .` `git commit -m "my first commit"` `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:[MyNameHere]/hello_app.git` and `git push -u origin --all`

Comment: Thank you very much!! For anyone who happens to google this or find this through stackoverflow, here's exactly when/how to perform the above steps: remake your cloud9 project from scratch. It'll be a lot faster the second time; just breeze through the tutorial commands. Once you reach the very bottom of page 47, follow along with Popescu's instructions above. Afterward do all of them again, but substitute "git add -A" in place of "git add ." You might be able to do this the first time around, but to be on the safe side I fully followed Popescu's instructions first. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create another project on your computer, copy the files you need from the old one and then run in this order from /workspace/mynewproject folder: `git init` `git add .` `git commit -m "my first commit"` `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:[MyNameHere]/hello_app.git` and `git push -u origin --all`